# Using instanceof with typescript union types CustomObject | CustomObject[]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently trying to implement a union type for a component input

`@Input('role') role: Role | Role[];`

where role is

```
enum Role { /**/ }
```

however when I am using the variable later in the code

`userHasRole(role: Role): boolean`

`if (userHasRole(this.role)) { /**/ }`

it throws an error since the role is an array or a single object and the method only allows a single object.

To try and get around this I have wrapped this code in an if statement using instanceof to check

```
if (this.role instanceof Role) { 
   if (userHasRole(this.role) { /**/ }
}
```

yet the type checker is still throwing errors about it possibly being an array, how can I get around this?

There are 2 errors that I am getting one from the method call

`ts2345 argument of type 'Role | Role[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Role'. Type 'Role[]' is not assignable to type 'Role'.`

and from the instanceof check

`ts2359 the right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.`

Comment: You should always write the exact error message

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce this.  Please make sure you post a [mcve] if you want meaningful help.

Comment: Ok I added the error messages and also added that the type is an enum

Comment: You can't use `instanceof` with an `enum` type. I'm surprised you aren't getting errors related to `this.role instanceof Role`. You should be able to use `Array.isArray(this.role)` though.

Comment: @Aaron that is where I am getting an error, is there another way to do this or am I stuck with switching the Input to only accept arrays? Also is there a possibility of using the ...args in its place?

Comment: Ah I see your error message now. Yes using `isArray()` would work. I'll post an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an `instanceof` expression with an `enum`. If `Role` was a class it would work.

You can use `Array.isArray()` to check if it's an array or a single value, and TS will correctly narrow the type in control flow.

Example:

```
if (!Array.isArray(this.role)) {
  // In here this.role has type Role
  if (userHasRole(this.role)) { /**/ }
} else {
  // In here this.role has type Role[] so you could do something like:
  if (this.role.includes(Role.SOME_ROLE)) { /**/ }
}
```

PS - I would think `userHasRole` should accept `Role | Role[]`...

Comment: Thanks! I ended up implementing this logic in the `userHasRole` method that way we can do this later on in different areas with ease!